# Adding a bimonthly view in KendoUI Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

How do I add a 15 day (bimonthly) view in Kendo UI Scheduler?

The idea is to show 15 days at a time (as opposed to 30 days in a month).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using custom timeline view ,

```
var MyCustomTimelistView = kendo.ui.TimelineMonthView.extend({
      options: {
        name: "MyCustomTimelistView",
        title: "Timeline Week",
        selectedDateFormat: "{0:D} - {1:D}",
        selectedShortDateFormat: "{0:d} - {1:d}",
        majorTick: 1440,
        **numberOfDays: 15**
      },
```

and then the view type will be "MyCustomTimelistView"

```
 var scheduler = $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
      startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
      height: 600,
      views: [{
        type: "**MyCustomTimelistView**",
        selected: true,
        dateHeaderTemplate: "<span class='k-link k-nav-day'>#=kendo.toString(date, ' dd/M ddd')#</span>"
      }],
```

Reference: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/custom-views/timeline-with-dynamic-length